# Does my file-parsing logic go in my file handler or code-behind in ASP.NET webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I'm new to ASP.NET and am working on a file parser and was wondering what the structure of my project should be. So far I have:

> **WebForm.aspx** (where my html/css/js goes. an upload button calls the filehandler)
>
> **WebForm.aspx.cs** (the code-behind. it's completely empty right now)
>
> **FileUpload.ashx.cs** (one class that posts the selected file to my server)
>
> **FileParser.cs** (classes that I have written/will write in C# already that will read in a file and parse it the way I like and return another file with the analytics and save to the user's computer)

I'm wondering where the FileParser.cs files should go. I need to be able to read the contents into an object that will parse the file to do some analytics and then give the user a "Save to computer" button on the next page to save the analytics file. I'm guessing I also need another handler for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fileparser.cs` must go to the `App_Code` folder, or you can create a new dll library and compile it, then place it to Bin directory of your asp.net

Then the classes inside the fileparser.cs can be accessed by the code behind.

More to read:
[ASP.NET Web Project Folder Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex526337.aspx)
[Shared Code Folders in ASP.NET Web Site Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23(v=vs.90).aspx)
[Codebehind and Compilation in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163675.aspx)